# How to point phpcbf to the folder standards?

Tags: coding-standards

After installing [**PHP_CodeSniffer**](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419988) on *Kali* with *composer*, I added point phpcs to the folder with standards (Drupal & DrupalPractice) where they are located, to run [**CodeSniffer globally by alias** **phpcs**](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419988#s-point-phpcs-to-the-new-standard):

> phpcs --config-set installed_paths
> ~/.config/composer/vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer

***Check of standards***:

> phpcs -i

```
The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR2, PSR12, Squiz, Zend, Drupal, DrupalPractice, VariableAnalysis and SlevomatCodingStandard
```

**Steps:**

1. Try to do the same things for **phpcbf**, doesn't have ***--config-set*** property or something similar to that work.
2. Add alias to the **.zshrc** file, doesn't see the folder with standards.

> phpcbf -i

```
The installed coding standards are Zend, MySource, PSR12, Squiz, PEAR, PSR1 and PSR2
```

Is there another ways to add point to the standards but for **phpcbf**?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is the exact duplicate of the previous question, which was closed. Deleting it and re-posting the same question doesn't fix the issue with the question.

Comment: Hello, @apaderno. 
How can I delete old one question [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311719/how-to-point-phpcbf-to-the-folder-standards] and stay to work only with this, current question?

Comment: Actually, instead of posting again the same question, you should have edited the previous one. It's a bad idea to delete questions, since the system keep in consideration the deleted questions to block users from asking further questions.

Comment: Anyway, questions with an up-voted answer cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to run it globally in a shell, use a [Composer script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md).

For example, this is from my `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "code-sniff": [
        "./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Drupal,DrupalPractice --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,info,txt,md --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor,*.min.* ./web/modules/custom ./web/themes/custom"
    ],
```

To run this, you can just do `composer code-sniff`.  That way, all the paths will be local and all the automatic discovery stuff will work as expected.

If you want a bash alias to run that, you can do something like `alias checkmycode='cd /my/drupal/dir;composer code-sniff'`.

This technique should work for phpcbf as well.